# Two problems in list manipulation

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a 3 by 3 matrix, in which each element is a 2 by 1 matrix.

1. How can I get rid of the zeros and change my matrix to a 3 by 3 matrix in which each element is a number?
2. How can I keep the zeros and just change the 3 by 3 matrix to a 3 by 6 Matrix (get rid of the internal matrix forms and just keep the numbers)?

```
 {{{0., 0.0516705 Subscript[a, i, 1]}, {0., -0.0499662 Subscript[a, i, 2]}, 
   {0., 0.0189977 Subscript[a, i, 3]}}, 
  {{0., -0.0499662 Subscript[a, i, 1]}, {0., 0.0706682 Subscript[a, i, 2]}, 
   {0., -0.0539635 Subscript[a, i, 3]}}, 
  {{0., 0.0189977 Subscript[a, i, 1]}, {0., -0.0539635 Subscript[a, i, 2]}, 
   {0., 0.0741863 Subscript[a, i, 3]}}}
```

Comment: `mat[[All, All, 2]]`, maybe.  And look up `ArrayReshape[mat, {3, 6}]` to see if it does what you want.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you Michael, It works. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is record as an answer the solution given by MichaelE2 in a comment.

```
m =
  {{{0., 0.0516705 Subscript[a, i, 1]}, {0., -0.0499662 Subscript[a, i, 2]}, 
    {0., 0.0189977 Subscript[a, i, 3]}}, 
   {{0., -0.0499662 Subscript[a, i, 1]}, {0., 0.0706682 Subscript[a, i, 2]}, 
    {0., -0.0539635 Subscript[a, i, 3]}}, 
   {{0., 0.0189977 Subscript[a, i, 1]}, {0., -0.0539635 Subscript[a, i, 2]}, 
    {0., 0.0741863 Subscript[a, i, 3]}}};

m1 = m[[All, All, 2]]
```

> ```
> {{0.0516705 Subscript[a, i, 1], -0.0499662 Subscript[a, i, 2], 
>   0.0189977 Subscript[a, i, 3]}, 
>  {-0.0499662 Subscript[a, i, 1], 0.0706682 Subscript[a, i, 2], 
>   -0.0539635 Subscript[a, i, 3]}, 
>  {0.0189977 Subscript[a, i, 1], -0.0539635 Subscript[a, i, 2], 
>   0.0741863 Subscript[a, i, 3]}}
> ```

```
m2 = ArrayReshape[m, {3, 6}]
```

> ```
> {{0., 0.0516705 Subscript[a, i, 1], 0., -0.0499662 Subscript[a, i, 2], 
>   0., 0.0189977 Subscript[a, i, 3]}, 
>  {0., -0.0499662 Subscript[a, i, 1], 0., 0.0706682 Subscript[a, i, 2], 
>   0., -0.0539635 Subscript[a, i, 3]}, 
>  {0., 0.0189977 Subscript[a, i, 1], 0., -0.0539635 Subscript[a, i, 2], 
>   0., 0.0741863 Subscript[a, i, 3]}}
> ```